# How do I compare the length of element in array

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have the following code:

```
sentence_array = ["hello", "hi", "bonjour"]
```

I'd like to be able to output the word that's the longest of the 3 elements.  I know I should probably use `sentence_array.each` but I'm stuck on how to proceed.

Comment: Welcome to SO, and to Ruby!  Remember, questions are supposed to show some research effort.  That's probably why someone (not me) gave you a -1 (downvote).

Comment: I've been tried researching for the past hour.  I'm on chapter 2 of the book and I'm just trying some exercises but the ruby documentation is a bit over my head at the moment.  Sorry for the vague question but there's a lot of unknown unknowns at the moment lol

Comment: No worries.  Don't let a few downvotes on here discourage you.  Read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and ask a better question next time :)

Comment: Thanks @JaredBeck .  I'll be honest, the negative thing was intimidating lol but I'm glad there are people like you on here.

Comment: @StevenWin the [`max_by` documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-max_by) contains exactly this example (finding the longest word in an array). You should really read the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way:

```
sentence_array.sort_by {|e| e.length} .last
#=> "bonjour"
```

Comment: This works great thanks!  I was thinking I'd have to pull out the element and compare each one but this is so simple.  Really enjoying Ruby over PHP so far.

Comment: There is no need to sort the array to find the maximum element. Just use `max_by`.

Answer (score 3):

`sentence_array.max_by(&:length)`

The [enumerable](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-max_by) module is one you will learn to love.

Comment: +1 I prefer this answer (`max_by(&:length)`) but I'd teach a complete beginner Yu Hao's `sort_by` first. :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'll have to research more on that